# ESLint prefer-arrow-callback error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I've got a problem with ESLint

Here is my function:

```
$productItem.filter(function (i, el) {
        return el.getBoundingClientRect().top < evt.clientY
    }).last()
    .after($productItemFull)
```

And Here is what ESLint tell me:

```
warning  Missing function expression name  func-names
error    Unexpected function expression    prefer-arrow-callback
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is basically saying to use [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax in the `filter` callback function.

```
$productItem.filter((i, el) => el.getBoundingClientRect().top < evt.clientY)
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    .last()
    .after($productItemFull);
```

Here's what [ESLINT documentation for `prefer-arrow-callback`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback) says

> Arrow functions are suited to callbacks, because:
>
> - `this` keywords in arrow functions bind to the upper scope’s.
> - The notation of the arrow function is shorter than function expression’s.

And, in following cases the error will be thrown

> ```
> /*eslint prefer-arrow-callback: "error"*/
>
> foo(function(a) { return a; });
> foo(function() { return this.a; }.bind(this));
> ```

Your code is same same as the first snippet. So, the error `prefer-arrow-callback` is shown by ESLint.

To solve the error, you can

1. use [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax(as shown above)
2. Suppress the error by using [options](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback#allownamedfunctions) and named function

   ```
   /*eslint prefer-arrow-callback: ["error", { "allowNamedFunctions": true }]*/

   foo(function bar() {});
   ```

Answer (score -1):

to solve "**unexpected function expression. (prefer-allow-callback)**" error in eslint write this code in the beginning of your code:

`/*eslint prefer-arrow-callback: 0*/`